# I need help factoring 6q(7(6q)^2 +5)

Tags: factoring

Can someone please show me how to factor $6q(7(6q)^2 +5)$ to show that it is a multiple of 6? I'm working on a division algorithm problem, and I understand concepts of div alg but I really don't have much experience factoring and I can't find any good sources on learning this type of thing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't it a multiple of $6$ because you are *multiplying* it by $6$?

Answer (score 2):

You already have shown it:

The quantity:
$$6q(7(6q)^2 +5)$$

Is divisible by $6$ because of the quantity $6q$ in front of the parenthesis. The $6$ implies that the polynomial is divisible by $6$.

Comment: True. Ok, thank you. For some reason I was thinking I had to isolate the 6 from the q.